# Symfony 5 How to create a form using paramconverter as value for one of the field

Tags: forms, symfony

I made a form that works with two tables joined (OneToMany, a strategy can have many strenghts), but I could only make it work with 'choice_label' for the 'strategy' field, as shown below.

Instead of the 'choice_label' which gives the user a list of strategies to choose from by titles, I want my code to retrieve the value of the paramconverter {title} used in my controller functions to identify which strategy is wanted, so that when the form is filled and sent, it automatically sets the strenght to the right strategy.

I looked into the many FormType Field of the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html), and tried option like 'data' instead of 'choice_label' but couldn't make it work. Thank you for your help !

My FormType file :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('strenght')
        ->add('strategy', EntityType::class,[
            'class' => Strategy::class,
            'choice_label' => 'title'
        ])
    ;
}
```

My Controller file :

```
public function createUpdate(DiagnosticForce $diagnosticforce = null, Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em)
{
    if(!$diagnosticforce){
        $diagnosticforce = new DiagnosticForce();
    }
    $form = $this->createForm(DiagnosticForceType::class, $diagnosticforce);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
        $em->persist($diagnosticforce);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute("frContentStrategy");
    }

    return $this->render('content_strategy/createForce.html.twig', [
        "diagnosticforce" => $diagnosticforce,
        "form" => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is : use the array $options inside your FormType to get the data you need, by sending it from your controller as the third argument of your createForm function, here in my controller : ['title' => $id] ; and then in your FormType you will be able to get that data just before $builder, and use it in your ->add (in this example, as the value for 'choices')

Here are my files and the solution :

FormType file :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $this->title = $options['title'];
    $builder
        ->add('strenght')
        ->add('strategy', EntityType::class,[
            'class' => Strategy::class,
            'choices' => [$this->title]
        ])
    ;
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => DiagnosticForce::class,
        'title' => null
    ]);
}
```

Controller File :

```
public function createUpdate(Strategy $id, DiagnosticForce $diagnosticforce = null, Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em)
{
    if(!$diagnosticforce){
        $diagnosticforce = new DiagnosticForce();
    }
    
    $form = $this->createForm(DiagnosticForceType::class, $diagnosticforce, [
        'title' => $id
    ]);
```